# How can I mount USB or EncFS resource as regular user?

Tags: mount, sudo, freebsd

How can I mount/unmount USB or EncFS resource as regular user?

Currently I have to use `sudo`.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-allow-ordinary-users-mount-cd-rom-dvds-usb-removabledevice/

Answer (score 0):

## EncFs

Steps

1. Add to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

   ```bsh
   vfs.usermount=1
   ```
2. Add your user to `operator` group (necessity of this step is not verfied)

   ```bsh
   pw groupmod operator -m <user>
   ```

Now, you can use EncFS as regular user.

Credits for Artem S. Tashkinov as he shared the link with the article above.

## USB Drive

I use [`automount`](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/automount/).

Simple install it, like

```bsh
sudo pkg install automount
```

and everything is handled automatically when you plug-in/plug-out USB Drives.

Alternatively, You can also use [`sysutils/dsbmd`](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/dsbmd/).

## GUI File Manager

I haven't figure out how to get a proper permission in Caja File Manager (if you use [Mate Desktop Environement](https://mate-desktop.org/)).
So I ended up with `automount` adding an extra volume in Caja File Manager (next to one detected by Caja which I don't have permission to unmount it. Interestingly, I can mount it.)

However, I can live with that until I find a solution to make it work in Caja.